# angular 2, select with dynamic option issues

Tags: angular, data-binding, html-select

In Angular 2, I create a select with dynamic options, options (item array) will be changed

```
<select [(ngModel)]="itemFilter" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item.name">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

1. item array is blank, then the select is empty with blank
2. item array is ["abc"], select contained "abc", then I select the "abc"
3. item array becomes ["abc", "def"] and select contained "abc","def" options but the selected "abc" become blank, ngModel is still "abc" but just the select display blank and it looks like it select blank

I assume that ngModel value is "abc" but the options (item array) is changed, then the ngModel binding is broken so the selected item become blank

Did anyone come across the similar issue?